# HTTP cookie shared between main domain and www

Tags: http, cookies, subdomain

How to create a HTTP cookie that is shared between www.example.com and example.com, but not other sub-domains?

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("today", "friday");
cookie.setDomain("example.com")  -> avaliable to all subdomains
```

How to make the cookie available to example.com and www.example.com only? not abc.example.com. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot, a cookie set on `.example.com` would be shared between www and non-www, but also any example.com subdomain.